# File permissions changed when using Copy (file syncing software)

Tags: permissions, cloud, user-management, copy.com

I just started using Copy, and it seems great, though I am having one difficulty. I'm running two Xubuntu Linux computers, one at work and one at home. The one at work is 64 bit and the one at home is 32 bit (I don't know if this is a problem or not, though presumably it shouldn't be). The problem is that when I drop a file into the /Copy folder from either end it'll show up on the other computer but with its permissions changed.

Specifically, if I write a test ASCII file in emacs and save it, it'll have the permissions:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1
```

However, it'll show up on the other end with permissions:

```
-rwx------ 1
```

This can be particularly annoying, especially since executable files are colored green by the shell. Is there any fix around this?

Comment: Same problem. Ever find a solution?

Comment: @Michael.Lumley, no, unfortunately I didn't. I can't say that I spent a great deal of time trying to figure it out after posting this question. I couldn't find anything else online regarding it and don't have access to the Copy source.

Comment: Somewhere there is a "preserve" permissions tag or option, which keeps the same permissions of the copied file.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `rsync` to copy your files. The `-p` option will preserve permissions and so many options:

```
-p          --> Preserve permissions 
-E          --> Preserve Executability
-o          --> Preserve OwenrShip
-g          --> Preserve Groups
-t          --> Preserve modifition time
```

for further redings use this [link](http://www.tecmint.com/rsync-local-remote-file-synchronization-commands/)

Comment: As the manual indicates, `-a` covers most "preserve" settings. `-avuz` will preserve practically everything (`-a`), only update files (`-u`, i.e. don't copy if the file is present in the destination and equal to the one in the source), compress before sending (`-z`) and be verbose about what's happening (`-v`).

Answer (score 3):

`cp` also can copy files preserving permissions, ownership etc. For this you need to use the `--preserve` switch. Here's the corresponding manual entry:

```
--preserve[=ATTR_LIST]
preserve the specified attributes (default:
mode,ownership,timestamps), if possible additional attributes:
context, links, xattr, all
```

But as Fiximan suggested `cp -a` would be simpler. From man pages again,

```
-a, --archive ; same as -dR --preserve=all
```

So the command would be something like:

```
cp -a <source> <destination>
```

---

That being said, since you are copying files, especially between a computer at work to home via the internet, it is best to use `scp`. `scp` has the `-p` switch which will preserve modification times, access times, and modes from the original file. You may also want to use the `-r` switch to recursively copy folders and subfolders. [Here](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/scp.htm) is a good guide on how use scp to transfer files.

Comment: `cp -a` would be simpler. From `man cp` : " -a, --archive ; same as -dR --preserve=all" ; or since it's remote: `scp -p`

Answer (score 1):

If you are vendor-locked on [Copy](http://copy.com), you can ask support on their site about preserving attributes.

If you have GUI, I suggest to use [FreeFileSync](https://www.freefilesync.org/).

It

- is open-source (GPLv3) software;
- works great with local and remote (FTP, SMB/CIFS, SSH via GVFS) files;
- compares by attributes and by content;
- have flexible sync settings (two way, mirror, update, custom);
- has real-time sync agent;
- preserves attributes and allows to copy file access permissions.

Also you can try [Unison](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/) (Ubuntu [package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=unison&searchon=names&exact=1&suite=all&section=all) available) or any other program from [Wikipedia list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_synchronization_software#Open_source).